# What are the outputs from my cable?

Tags: cables, breadboard, electret, cable-assemblies, coaxial

I am in the process of building a microphone connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico. To check my expectations are correct, I have bought a pre-assembled electret mic and amplifier. The issue I have, is I haven't used this type of connector before. Here is an image:
[image: Coaxial cables]

The amplifier has 3 outputs labelled as A (yellow wire), G (black wire) amd V (red wire). These 3 wires are then somehow split into 2 outputs, with the heads shown in the above image.

The 2 cables leading to each head contain - a red and exposed copper wire for the red head - a yellow and exposed copper wire for the white head.

My thinking so far is that:

- G represents ground, matching the colour black
- A represents audio ( that is, the signal the mic detects )
- this leaves V, which I assume must be the power supply for the mic

If others can see an error here, please opine, although I expect I could remove the later part of the connector and use these three wires.

Ideally, I would like to keep using the cabling as-is, so:

How do the three wires, labelled A, V and G, convert to two heads (in the above image) containing a covered wire and exposed wire each ?

Further, how would I go about connecting these heads to a bread board - I would like to use basic wiring.

I also have these components, if it would help:

[image: connectors]

Comment: We don't know what you bought and how does it work and what colour wires are for what purpose. Care to include a link? Also how do you intend to connect it to a Pico and what would be the use for this? What are the specs of the amplifier output, to know if it is compatible or possible to adjust to be compatible with Pico input.

Comment: The product was bought custom made - there is no link to the complete product. The cable connecting the amplifier to the heads in the images, of which my question is primarily about, I believe are standard issue.

Comment: If the product is custom made, who knows how it connects to the cable. You should ask the people who custom made it. The cable is just a cable and you can use a multimeter to find out if it connects like you expect.

Comment: @PeterBennett The other one clearly isn't. Likely audio for RCA and DC plug for power.

Answer (score 0):

The white one is a standard connector for audio and video.  So it's going to be the amplified audio.

The other is a barrel connector, typically used for supplying power. *Don't assume that the centre pin is positive - check before you apply power.*